# Using document.write with getElementById and innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have been playing with this for a while but can't get it to work. Anyone know how I can take text from an element like DIV and use it in document write.

Not sure why this doesn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
document.write("<sc"+"ript>"+document.getElementById('hi').innerHTML+"</scr"+"ipt>");
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="hi" style="color:white">alert('test');</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What doesn't work about it? Describe.

Answer (score 1):

The javascript needs to come after the html. The `<div id="hi>"` doesn't exist yet when the script is run.

For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <div id="hi" style="color:white">alert('test');</div>
    <script>
        document.write("<sc"+"ript>"+document.getElementById('hi').innerHTML+"</scr"+"ipt>");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Haha, thanks! Brain fart. That's what I get for waking up so early :-)

Answer (score 0):

This script will run immediatly before the browser has loaded the  below. Try moving the script to the bottom of the page <del>or you can place it in the body's onload event handler</del>.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="hi" style="color:white">alert('test');</div>
        <script>
            document.write("<sc"+"ript>"+document.getElementById('hi').innerHTML+" </scr"+"ipt>");
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Putting the script in the onload handler will cause the `document.write` call to overwrite the existing document.